# Tag editing gone rogue

Tags: support, tagging, editing, retagging

When reporting a new layout bug to the design change thread, I noticed the following:

[image]
(many irrelevant tags)

But hitting the "edit" button ("edit tags" won't work due to layout issues) I get this:
[image]

where are the others? I double-checked back to [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209021/construction-of-a-lipschitz-function) and the missing tags were still present.

---

After removing one of the tags, the others appeared in the box, so this seems to be a layout issue.

To see this layout bug, try to [edit the first revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1209021/edit/da49ed12-bfaf-452b-92ec-1b3c6cf802b2).

If the box showed half of another tag, it would be more obvious, that these are not the only tags:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You see the end of the line, which is too long to be shown in full. The others are at the start of the line, and you should be able to move the cursor there.

This is optimized for adding tags and/or removing/changing the more rare ones that are at the end. The cursor is always placed at the end of that line.

What is true is that it leaves perhaps a bit too much white-space at the expense of showing a bit more of the tags.

Comment: I've brought it up as a [layout issue](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20084/86940) now, together with a related bug. What stumped me was that there is extremely much whitespace next to the two tags, so showing part of the preceeding tags wouldn't take up too much space but would clarify that we don't see it all.

Comment: I edited my answer independently somewhat along these lines. Sometimes half a tag is shown. Where the cut-off is likely depends on the length of the tags and other things.  I am not sure how exactly this is decided, and how easy or difficult it would be to always show a cut-off tag. It could be suggestive but it might not be worth the effort (if it is not small). // IMO this has nothing  to do with the new layout (or at least it is tangential). The phenomenon itself is old and not unique to this site (let alone the new layout)  I think it is *not* a good idea to mention it there.

Comment: I hadn't noticed this problem in the old layout, are you sure it existed? The first issue in my answer definitely relates to the new layout (maybe some vertical spacing causes a mouse-out event when crossing the lines).

Comment: The issue exists also in the MO layout and the  MESE layout (that is the beta-theme). I cannot claim to have a highly specific recollection of having seen it here, but then this is not surprising as I considered this behavior as the standard behavior before even doing any edit on this site. Counter question: what was the behavior before the change in your recollection? (It was hardly a multiline field, or never too long, so the only thing that could have been is that thet cursor was at the start and not the end, I doubt that but cannot strictly exclude it..)

Comment: It was similar to my second screen-shot. Particularly the space to the right of the applied tags was much smaller (about half).

Comment: This does not change the substance. Even if there is less white-space -- this might be desirable, I agree -- with different tag-length it would still have cut-off at a full tag. So then you would miss one or two instead of three. (Likely missing one would be the most confusing as one might think one has accidentally already deleted it.) If you want to report too much white space in the new layout go ahead. The rest is not "new layout."